# How can a command in a pipe read from a keyboard?

Tags: ssh, bash, terminal

I randomly tried to execute the following command in bash<sup>1</sup>

```
cat /some/file | ssh user@machine 'cat >/destination/file
```

There are no keys installed on the remote machine, so the only way to authenticate is with the password mechanism. I thought this wouldn't work, since the pipe will disconnect SSH's stdin from the terminal. I was surprised when I was prompted for a password, and the file was successfully sent.

Any thoughts on how SSH is able to read the keyboard to prompt for a password, despite not being connected to it?

---

<sup>1</sup>I am aware there are better alternatives to copying a file between two machines.

Comment: How can it know which terminal to read from? Where does it get that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Open)ssh reads directly from the tty. See:

- http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/usr.bin/ssh/readpass.c?rev=1.51&content-type=text/plain where it calls readpassphrase.
- [How does ssh prompt for a password when all input and output is redirected?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171835/how-does-ssh-prompt-for-a-password-when-all-input-and-output-is-redirected)

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /some/file | ssh user@machine 'cat >/destination/file
```

This does not work, because `ssh` truncates its `stdin` before displaying prompt and reading a password (security). Possible workaround is to use `expect` script, which will interact with running `ssh` process.

Comment: It does work for me, the file is transferred completely and correctly.