# Redirect all output, including input prompts

Tags: io-redirection, prompt, file-descriptors

I know that doing `command &> /dev/null` suppresses all output file descriptors.

But I notice that it does not work for commands that request input from the user, most notably `ssh`:

```
> ssh blah@blah.org &>/dev/null
blah@blah.org's password:
```

**Where is this output coming from? And why is not supressed?**

One way I've found is to look up the process ID, and find file descriptors being used via

`lsof -p <pid>`

which shows (for example) `/dev/pts/3`, which I can then do

`echo -en "\rMy own Custom Password Input Prompt:" > /dev/pts/3`

which overrides the prompt, but this is a workaround at best.

Comment: Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/117549

Comment: Also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171835/117549

Comment: I see - it writes directly to the tty if outputs are suppressed. Thanks